# How many Unique Combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve a programming problem which I have so far reduced to the following.  The actual problem looks nothing like this, but on analysis, I came up with this simplified way to solve it, but alas I don't have the combinations knowledge.  This is a step to help solve 'cebwrpgrhyre dhrfgvba svsgrra' (rot-13)

How many unique orderings are there of drawing balls from a bag.  There are 2 colors of balls, and 10 of each color.  So one possible unique combination would be 'rrrrrrrrrrbbbbbbbbbb' (if it were red and blue colors).

What part of combination theory can I read about to solve this?  Keywords I should have searched?

Edit:  all balls must be drawn to count as a combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you consider balls of a given colour to be indistinguishable, you choose $10$ of the $20$ positions to be $r$ and the others are $b$.  So the answer is
$\displaystyle {20 \choose 10} = 184756$

Comment: Thanks, but how do I arrive at that number?  I don't just need the right answer, I need to understand so I can write a function.

Comment: The name of the $$\binom{A}{B}$$ operator is itself suggestive. It's read as $A$ choose $B$, and denotes the number of ways to choose $B$ things from a group of $A$ things. The things chosen are unordered and without replacement.

Comment: @RobertKerr $\binom{a}{b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$